# font-not-found error: font "HoeflerText" cannot be found -- LuaLaTex error!

Tags: xetex, luatex, fontspec, windows

I am running this CV/Resume example from [here](http://www.cv-templates.info/2009/06/advanced-two-column-latex-cv-template-part-2-tex-source/):

Here is a relevant fraction of the code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
%!TEX encoding =  UTF-16
% See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.
\usepackage[hmargin=1.25cm, vmargin=1.5cm]{geometry}
%symbols - the ones you see on the left of the email and of the phone
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{eurosym}
%Colors/Graphics
\usepackage{color,graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

%Fonts and Tweaks for XeLaTeX
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Hoefler Text}
...
```

So... when compiling with LuaLaTeX (part of MiKTeX on Windwos XP x64), I am getting the following error:

```
...
luaotfload | Font names database loaded: C:/Documents and Settings/Ampleforth/L
ocal Settings/Application Data/MiKTeX/2.9/luatex-cache/generic/names/otfl-names
.lua
luaotfload | Updating the font names database:
luaotfload | Scanning TEXMF and OS fonts...
luaotfload | Font names database saved: %s 
: C:/Documents and Settings/Ampleforth/Local Settings/Application Data/MiKTeX/2
.9/luatex-cache/generic/names/otfl-names.lua

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
! 
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "HoeflerText" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.28 \setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Hoefler Text}
```

What is wrong? How can I install this font so LuaLaTeX is picking it up? Where to download? Any other thoughts about this?

Comment: Based on the first answer and your response, the question is now "how do I acquire and install the Hoefler Text font on my Windows machine?" That's sort of out of the scope of this site but google is your friend.

Comment: If your new fonts are in `~/.fonts` and not being recognized by `mkluatexfontdb`, try this: OSFONTDIR=${HOME}/.fonts:/usr/share/fonts//:/usr/share/texmf/fonts// mkluatexfontdb --force --verbose=-1 -vvv **EDIT** This is for `Linux`. For Windows sth equivalent ought to apply, though...

Comment: A this question is about installing the font on Windows, and it's system dependent, I suggest make your Linux answer to a comment instead or comment-link to your answer [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122079) which is exactly the same. Alternatively, you could change it to work with Windows, than it can remain as real answer of course.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz Generally agree, but I was so happy to find the solution after hours of plowing, that I can imagine others will benefit from knowing this, too. A comment is much less visible in comparison... I consider this a case of *helpful redundancy*. Haven't booted Windows in ages, but maybe someone who's currently using Windows can improve my answer to apply to Windows (, too)?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is really about fonts available (or otherwise) on a particular operating system, not the use of fonts with TeX.

Answer (score 11):

Hoefler Text is distributed with Mac OS X; I don't know if it can be used on a Windows system, as it is not an OpenType font. Just change the line

```
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Hoefler Text}
```

to

```
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}
```

or any other system font you have.

Notice that `\setromanfont` is deprecated in favor of `\setmainfont`, but that's not the problem. Also `Mapping=tex-text` is to be changed into `Ligatures=TeX`. because the latter form is compatible with LuaLaTeX (the former isn't).

Comment: I know, but it relaly looks cool and makes all the flavour in that layout. So, I am honestly looking for a way to migrate the font over to windows. Are there perhaps any fonts that look very similar or is there a way to convert with some sort of tool?

Comment: Looks like [you can purchase Hoefler Text](http://www.typography.com/fonts/font_styles.php?productLineID=100010) for use on one computer for ~$300. It looks like Wikipedia used to set their logo in Hoefler Text until they switched to the free font [Linux Libertine](http://www.linuxlibertine.org/). Perhaps that would be an acceptable alternative.

Comment: The Hoefler Text file distribuited with OSX cannot be used on another platform. It seems to be something only OS X can read. This is a shame ,as Hoefler Text is a really nice, complete font in my opinion. I've tried on my linux box to get it to work, but without success.

Comment: @Mica: there are tools that convert fonts in `.dfont` format to TrueType. This doesn't imply it's legal.

Comment: @egreg — right, I'm pretty sure it's *not* legal to even transfer the font to another computer, let alone to convert it into another format. Regardless, I seem to remember that these fonts are ‘crippled’ in a way that precludes a convenient way to convert them to OpenType, but that could have been an older version of the fonts.

Comment: On newer systems, Hoefler Text is an ordinary `.ttc` font which can be used everywhere. I've just tried it on my Linux machine, no problems.