# using a Postscript Type 1 font with fontspec and LuaLaTex on MacOSX

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec

I am having trouble using SabonLT which is a Postscript Type 1 Outline font. I have the font installed as a system font (as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103704/how-to-properly-install-and-use-a-new-font-with-lualatex)) rather than a local font. I'm running LuaLaTex on Mac OSX.

I have checked in `/Users/<username>/Library/texlive/2012/texmf
-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/otfl-names.lua` but indeed no Sabon font is listed there.

I have tried both with and without the path specification in the fontspec call:
`\setmainfont[Path=/Library/Fonts/]{Sabon LT}`. (Though there is no way to specify the extension because [Postscript Type 1 fonts don't have one](http://www.acutesystems.com/fonts.htm).)

But no matter what I do I get the following error: `fontspec error: "font-not-found"`.

Comment: I don't think that luaotfload (used by fontspec) handles type1 fonts - at least not the version from texlive 2012. You will have to create a tfm file and use it in the "standard" way.

Comment: type 1 fonts (``pfa`` and ``pfb``) aren’t indexed by ``luaotfload``. They should, however, work as absolute paths (e.g. ``\font\foo=[/path/to/font.pfa]``, idk how to do that with fontspec) or if the file can be found by kpathsea.

Comment: @phg doesn't work here (tl2012, lualatex)

Comment: @dıʞsdoʇ true, sorry for the noise. The current version reads pfa just fine.

Comment: @phg I tried to load a `pfb` in TL13 through an absolute path. luaotfload could find the font but not use the font itself. After I made run an update of TL13 (which included a luaotfload update) I now get an error message: `! LuaTeX error .../texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-loaders.lua:17: a
ttempt to index global 'readers' (a nil value).` There is no problem with open type fonts.

Comment: @ulrike-fischer see [this commit](https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/commit/1a66cdf2619cbbb8cd43b40200e265d52a321a85) that hasn’t made it into ctan yet.

Comment: @phg: Great. Btw (seeing the `fonts.readers`): I have read with great delight in the documentation that some efforts have been made to create an interface for package authors. But imho it is unclear which part of the fonts table one should manipulate if some data is stored in more than one place.

Comment: @ulrike-fischer the *correct* one ``;-)``. That is, where the fontloader puts it initially. All additions installed by ``add_fontdata_fallbacks`` are supposed to be pure compatibility fallbacks for older versions of fontspec and the likes. Once we are confident all distros have updated, those fallbacks will be gone in an instant, and with them the duplication.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Any development about this issue? If there is, please add an answer.

Comment: @phg If you have any news about the problem, can you please make an answer?

Comment: Can LuaLaTeX really handle type 1 fonts which are in Mac format i.e. as resource forks on OS X? That is, even if LuaLaTeX can handle type 1 fonts of the usual sort, handling resource forks might be a further complication. If that is what you have - the bit on that web page about extensions you referenced concerns Mac fonts in a very non-standard format (from the point of view of other systems). Note that neither LaTeX nor pdfLaTeX could use type 1 fonts in that format, even though type 1 fonts of the more usual kind are their bread and butter. That info is outdated - at least for Linux.

Comment: @phg Can LuaTeX also make use of the relevant `.afm` files? If not, it cannot really use the `.pfb` or `.pfa` font except, maybe for something like a dingbat or ornament font, can it?

Comment: @cfr *Can LuaTeX also make use of the relevant .afm files?* -- Yes, that
functionality is exposed by means of the function ``fontloader.apply_afmfile()``.
Though AFAIR the Luaotfload fontloader does its own AFM parsing
and applies them similar to Opentype features.
See [the source](https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/blob/master/src/fontloader/misc/fontloader-font-afm.lua) for the gory details.

Comment: @phg Good to know - thanks. So it will find them in a separate directory e.g. in a texmf tree? Or do they need to be in the same directory as the `.pfb`?

Comment: @cfr AFM files are indexed along with [the other registered
formats](https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/blob/master/src/luaotfload-database.lua#L128)
when building the names database but not by default. That behavior
can be overridden by passing an appropriate ``--formats=…`` option
to ``luaotfload-tool`` or by setting the configuration option. (The
reason for not including them by default is that TeX distros ship
with tons of Type1 font files that only slow down the loading and
are rarely used with Luatex.)