# Installing a .otf font and using it with fontspec (LuaLaTeX on a Mac)

Tags: fonts, fontspec

I've downloaded an .otf font (specifically one called `Dalelands Uncial`) that I would like to use in a document.  I've double-clicked on the file and selected install, so that it now sits in my `~/Library/Fonts` folder on my Mac and Font Book claims the file is installed.

I thought that running LuaLaTeX on the following minimal example would now allow me to access the font, but it doesn't work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
    Path = /Users/<myname>/Library/Fonts,
    Extension = .otf,
    Ligatures = TeX
]{Dalelands Uncial}
\begin{document}
Some sample text.
\end{document}
```

(This is my attempt to replicate what is suggested in the first answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103704/how-to-properly-install-and-use-a-new-font-with-lualatex).)

I'm told that "DalelandsUncial" cannot be found.  Is it the space in the name causing a problem?

Comment: Try Dalelands_Uncial

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to specify either the path or the extension if the font has been installed. But as indicated by Yiannis, the mistake must be in the ``{Dalelands Unical}`` part.

Comment: Do you have an up-to-date Texlive 2014? If not a manual run of `luaotfload-tool --update` might be necessary

Comment: Tried those: "Dalelands_Uncial" gives the same error.  Also just ran `luaotfload-tool --update` and I still get the same error.

Comment: You definitely don't need the path and the extension. Open Font Book, select the font and hit Command-I: what does it list next to "Family"?

Comment: Does `luaotfload-tool --fuzzy --find=DalelandsUncial` return anything?  In the past I have found that XeTeX and LuaTeX expect different names for the same font. Does the file name match the 'internal' name?  Try, e.g., `otfinfo -i <fontfile>.otf`

Comment: I have downloaded the font from http://www.dafont.com/it/dalelands.font and installed it in `~/Library/Fonts`. Your document, after removing `Path=...` and `Extension=...` compiles without problems (LuaTeX triggers a run of `luaotfload-tool` the first time).

Comment: Ok - thanks all so far.  I'm beginning to conclude there is something wrong with my installation/setup.  When I run `luaotfload-tool --fuzzy --find=DalelandsUncial`, it claims it can find the file, but refers to a directory that I first tried putting it in, before I came across the above answer that I linked to.  This folder doesn't even exist any longer, so I guess I need to do some updating of the database?  I've tried `sudo luaotfload-tool -f -u` but that doesn't seem to have made any difference.

Comment: I've tried adding another named font to see what happens.  I downloaded the font, double-clicked it, installed it into `~/Library/Fonts` and then removed the original file.  `luaotfload-tool` can't find it.  My conclusion is that this is not searching my Fonts folder.  How do I tell it to look here?  (And how do I diagnose where it actually is looking?)

Comment: I also have a problem under Windows 7: I can use the font with `XeLaTeX`, and same problem with `LuaLaTeX`.

Answer (score 1):

With further experimentation, I have now found an answer that works for TeXlive as installed on my machine.  I have no idea why this one works for me, but the one that works for @egreg does not.

It turns out that all I needed to do was put the .otf files in a subdirectory of `~/Library/texlive/2014/texmf-var/fonts` and they can then be found by `LuaLaTeX`.