# LuaTeX compilation completed and no errors, yet font doesn't show up

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, luaotfload

I decided to try using some new fonts and LuaLaTeX, and so I downloaded some fonts and installed them using the instructions from the first answer in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103704/how-to-properly-install-and-use-a-new-font-with-lualatex). I put the setup into my preamble and compilation with LuaTeX worked, but what I got was Computer Modern instead of the installed fonts, so I'm not sure what's happening.

I also tried using `mkluatexfontdb --force --verbose=-1 -vvv`, but what happened was a `mkluatexfontdb: command not found` error, so I had to do it all manually by linking the correct folder.

Here is the font part of the setup in my preamble:

```
% Font / LuaLaTeX setup
\RequirePackage{iftex}
\ifpdftex
\ifluatex
    \RequirePackage{fontspec}
    \RequirePackage{unicode-math} 
    \unimathsetup{math-style=TeX}
    \RequirePackage[english]{babel}
    \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX, Scale=MatchLowercase}
    \setmainfont[
    Path=/usr/share/fonts/opentype/linux-libertine/,
    Extension=.otf,
    BoldFont=LinLibertine_RB,
    ItalicFont=LinLibertine_RI,
    BoltItalicFont=LinLibertine_RBI,
    ]{LinLibertine_R}
    \setsansfont[
    Path=/mnt/c/Users/user/Appdata/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Fonts, % yes I also added Windows fonts to the font dir and it appears when doing fc-list | grep -i <windows font>
    Extension=.otf,
    BoldFont=Kurier-Bold,
    ItalicFont=Kurier-Italic,
    BoldItalicFont=Kurier-BoldItalic,
    ]{Kurier-Regular}
    \setmonofont[
    Path=/mnt/c/Users/user/Appdata/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Fonts,
    Extension=.ttf,
    BoldFont=Inconsolata-Bold,
    ]{Inconsolata-Regular}
\else 
% regular times
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{newtxtext}
\RequirePackage[smallerops]{newtxmath}
\fi
\fi
```

Perhaps there's something in my preamble that I missed, or perhaps it's something else entirely. If someone knows how to solve this problem, it would be great. Thanks!

Comment: 9 years are long time. the tool is now call luaotfload-tool.  And your \if switches are wrong, you are actually excluding all the code.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you meant about the first sentence - did I load the fonts incorrectly? Additionally, I will check my `\if` switches right now - I tried something which uses nested `\if` and `\else`, but that could be wrong.

Comment: \ifpdftex is false if you use luatex.

Comment: Yep, that was it. I ran a test on a small tex file which outputs LuaLaTeX and some other test words if there is luatex and LaTeX with pdftex - only the first test worked. I changed that and made a few other changes which I didn't notice were causing errors and most of it worked. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer means there is no command `mkluatexfontdb ` it is called `luaotfload-tool` but you rarely need to run it directly, luatex updates its files automatically