# How to catch missing font error and use another font?

Tags: luatex, fontspec

I write a TeX-document on two PCs, the files are transferred via USB-Stick. 
The document should be printed with a specific font.
For legal reaons the font is only available on one PC.

When I translate the document in the PC without the font, I get a *fontspec error: "font-not-found"*. (same error in [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16894/font-not-found-error-font-hoeflertext-cannot-be-found-lualatex-error))

The finished document shows no characters.

Is there a mechanism to detect this problem and switch to another font?

Actually I change my font selection each time I change the computer.
But I want to avoid to use two versions of my style.
I would like to have one style for each computer.

A MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%This throws an error - I want to catch it and use another font
\setmainfont{My Font on other PC} 
%If error:
%\setmainfont{Arial} 
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

My wish:
This document will be translated without an error with lualatex on a windows PC.
If the font *My Font on other PC* is installed, it is used.
If it is not installed, the alternative should be used.

Answer (score 2):

Luatex may let you catch that I'm not sure, but a simpler method that would also work with classic TeX is to simply replace

```
\setmainfont{My Font on other PC}
```

by

```
\input{setdefaultfont}
```

then anywhere on the tex input path on the two machines you have a `setdefaultfont.tex` which you do *not* transfer between the machines.

On one machine the file has the line

```
\setmainfont{My Font on other PC}
```

and on the other it has the line

```
\setmainfont{Arial}
```

Comment: +1 What I don't like with this solution: `setdefaultfont.tex` must be defined on each new PC and if I get the font on my 2nd PC, I have to adapt setdefaultfont.tex. Let's see, if another solution will come up.

Comment: Instead You might prefer to have `\InputIfFileExists{setdefaultfont}{}{\setmainfont{Arial}}` then you only need the file on machines which are not going to use arial